# Transferring data from one database to another

Tags: sql-server, database, data-transfer

I have two databases, lets say Database A and B, with different datastructures. 
In Database A there is a table contacts.
In Database B there is a table Accounts.

I want to transfer data from Database A table contacts to Database B table Accounts.
I am use SQL Server 2005 and want to write sql scripts to do this.

Can someone tell me what's the easiest and most efficient way to achieve this:
a) If they are on the same SQL server
b) If they are on different SQL servers.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest method isn't necessarily the most efficient.  SSIS is likely the most efficient, as Mitch already indicated.

The easiest (if you don't know SSIS already) is to just set up a linked server to the remote DB, and SELECT the data across using four-part naming.  You set up a linked server using sp_addlinkedserver and sp_addlinkedsrvlogin (check BOL for the syntax), and query as follows:

```
INSERT INTO MyLocalTable (ColumnList)
SELECT <Columns> FROM RemoteServer.RemoteDB.RemoteSchema.RemoteTable
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron, 
I did some reading on SSIS. Amm is it true that SSIS only has graphical UI to do the mapping or is it possible to generate scripts once mapping has been completed so that it can be used multiple times. The system I am working on will run a stored procedure which reads data from database A into database B

Answer (score 1):

Use SSIS. It will work for both local and remote cases, and will enable you to set up a transform between the tables, to map columns to lother columns etc.

Comment: Thanks Mitch, 
I did some reading on SSIS. Amm is it true that SSIS only has graphical UI to do the mapping or is it possible to generate scripts once mapping has been completed so that it can be used multiple times. The system I am working on will run a stored procedure which reads data from database A into database B

Answer (score 1):

Is it a one off transfer?  If it's a simple transfer I write a SELECT statement to create the INSERT statements, i.e.

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO Accounts (ID, Name) VALUES (' + CAST(ID as VARCHAR) + ', ''' + Name  + ''')'
FROM Contacts
```

Run this on Database A - and it will spit out the all INSERT statements, which you copy and paste so you can run them on Database B.

Or, on the same database:

```
INSERT INTO DatabaseA.dbo.Accounts (ID, Name) 
SELECT Id, Name
FROM DatabaseB.dbo.Contacts
```

Still not happy - try setting up linked servers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks russau. Ya I need the operation multiple times.